# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined using calendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, calendar

I am working on calendar with `js` in my project for availabilities it works correctly. but when I have a record which has a start date equal an end date.
for add event to my calendar i'm using this push:

```
listDate.push({startDate :strDate, endDate : enDate});
```

in my script `datetimepicker` this is function `isAvailable`

```
isAvailable: function(date, month, year) {
      for (var i in this.unavailable) {
         var book_date = this.unavailable[i].startDate.split("-");
          if (book_date.length !== 3) {
             return false;
          } else if (
              (book_date[0] == "*" || book_date[0] - year === 0) &&
              (book_date[1] == "*" || book_date[1] - month === 0) &&
              (book_date[2] == "*" || book_date[2] - date === 0)
          ) {
              return false;
          }
       }
       return true;
    }
```

I get this issues: `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in this line`

```
  var book_date = this.unavailable[i].startDate.split("-");
```

please any help thanks for you

Answer (score 0):

`this.unavailable[i].startDate` is undefined. Does `listDate` reference `this.unavailable` or is it a different array? Put a breakpoint or use `console.log` to inspect the contents of `this.unavailable` in the `isAvailable` function.

Comment: result of console.log(this.unavailable) in the isAvailable function.{startDate: "2018-10-09", endDate: "2018-10-11"}
1
:
{startDate: "2018-10-10", endDate: "2018-10-11"}
2
:
     {startDate: "2018-10-11", endDate: "2018-10-11"}
3
:
{startDate: "2018-10-25", endDate: "2018-10-28"}
4
:
{startDate: "2018-10-26", endDate: "2018-10-28"}
5
:
{startDate: "2018-10-27", endDate: "2018-10-28"}
6
:
{startDate: "2018-10-28", endDate: "2018-10-28"}
length
:
7

Answer (score 0):

The code does not give me any error in my console. Can you try storing the value of `unavailable` in a separate variable and use that variable instead. This might help.

```
isAvailable: function(date, month, year) {
  var unavailable = this.unavailable;
  for (var i in unavailable) {
     var book_date = unavailable[i].startDate.split("-");
      if (book_date.length !== 3) {
         return false;
      } else if (
          (book_date[0] == "*" || book_date[0] - year === 0) &&
          (book_date[1] == "*" || book_date[1] - month === 0) &&
          (book_date[2] == "*" || book_date[2] - date === 0)
      ) {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: my code it's work but just when i have record in database like this  :    

{startDate: "2018-10-09", endDate: "2018-10-09"}    this give me Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
(i get error just when start date == end date )

Comment: i think for that case this.unavailable[i] does not have a property called startDate or the value of the property startDate is undefined. Did you try to put a breakpoint on that line and check the value of this.unavailable[i].startDate for that case ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for in loop to iterate through an array - for in loops should only be used on objects. You should use a plain for loop or forEach

```
isAvailable: function(date, month, year) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.unavailable.length; i++) {
     var book_date = this.unavailable[i].startDate.split("-");
      if (book_date.length !== 3) {
         return false;
      } else if (
          (book_date[0] == "*" || book_date[0] - year === 0) &&
          (book_date[1] == "*" || book_date[1] - month === 0) &&
          (book_date[2] == "*" || book_date[2] - date === 0)
      ) {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```